# How to give connection details for cassandra in properties file using datastax java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
Initializer myInitializer = ... // your implementation
Cluster cluster = Cluster.buildFrom(myInitializer);
```

Im trying to connect to *Cassandra*cluster with several node details mentioning in `addcontactpoints("192.1.1.1","192.2.2.2").build()`.

Now I want to connect to *Cassandra* cluster with out mentioning the in that method. I want to mention my node details in separate properties file and want to connect to my cluster using that properties file. I have got one method in Java driver called `getcontactpoint()`.

I'm not getting how to use that and implement it. Please help me to improve my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all nodes ip like below 
 nodes=192.1.1.1,192.2.2.2

In java Resource interface is there by using that you can get your properties file

Like ResourceBundle resource=ResourceBundle.getBundle("cassandra")

then by getProperty method you can get nodes  and split it by comma(,) so it will gives you Array of String mean all IP . 
Like
nodes=resource.getString("nodes")

then in method addContactPoints() just give nodes variable .

Like addContactPoints(nodes)

Comment: Thanks @mahendra sign, I tried what you said but when i'm using Resource im not getting getBundle() method.so I used ResouceBundle then i could get that getBundle() method after that i didnt get the getProperty() method for it so i used getString() but i was unable to do getting exception as Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name CassandraConnections, locale en_US i gave in my code as ResourceBundle rb=ResourceBundle.getBundle("CassandraConnections",Locale.ENGLISH);
  String nodes=rb.getString("nodes"); please help me clearly

Comment: did you create CassandraConnections.properties file in resource folder

Comment: did you running program using main method of java or on tomcat ? and created maven project of simple java project ?

Comment: don't need to give Locale.ENGLISH

Comment: import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ResourceBundleDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // create a new ResourceBundle with default locale
   ResourceBundle bundle =
   ResourceBundle.getBundle("hello");

   // print the text assigned to key "hello"
   System.out.println("" + bundle.getString("hello"));

   }
}                                                                                                                                it will work like this

Comment: yes when im using Resource im not getting the getBundle() method..if you don't mine,can you give me the clear code

Comment: yes i was able to get from your code after that im giving  cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(nodes).withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
    new TokenAwarePolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy())).build();         ---from here it is not able to connect to cluster

Comment: ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("cassandra");
  String[] nodes = bundle.getString("node").split(",");
  String password = bundle.getString("password");
  String user = bundle.getString("user");
  Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(nodes)
    .withCredentials(user, password).withPort(9042).build();

Comment: im getting this exception 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name CassandraConnections, locale en_US
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
 at cassandra_db_cli_dtastx.CassClusConnPropFile.<init>(CassClusConnPropFile.java:30)
 at cassandra_db_cli_dtastx.CassClusConnPropFile.main(CassClusConnPropFile.java:68)
Java Result: 1'  got same exception when "hello"

Comment: when i made changes now im getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "192.1.1.1","192.2.2.2"
 at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:839)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoints(Cluster.java:859)
 at cassandra_db_cli_dtastx.CassClusConnPropFile.connect(CassClusConnPropFile.java:52)
 at cassandra_db_cli_dtastx.CassClusConnPropFile.main(CassClusConnPropFile.java:70)
Java Result: 1

Comment: don't put ip in ""  in property file. just put  like 192.1.1.1,192.2.2.2

Comment: Thanks @mahendra singh..It worked me.Thanks for your help.